# Issues with displaying all comments on each post using angularjs php

Tags: php, angularjs

Am using the script below to display users post  and along with their comments uniquely based on the post id.

The Issue am having is that assuming in a post with id 1 which has about 69 comments with the post id. instead of the script to display 69 comments belonging to that post id, it will just display one comment for each post. can someone help me fix that. **I have also attach the screenshot showing the post and comment. It displays total comment for each post but display only one comment text/info per post**

below is the code

```
include "config.php";

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$request = $data->request;
$userid = 5;

// Get all posts list and like unlike
if($request == 1){

    $response_arr = array();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts11";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $postid = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $type = -1;


        $comment_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntComment, username as usern,comment as p_com FROM post_comment WHERE  type=1  and postid=".$postid;
        $comment_result = mysqli_query($con,$comment_query);
        $comment_row = mysqli_fetch_array($comment_result);

        $total_comment = $comment_row['cntComment'];

        $usern = $comment_row['usern'];
        $pcom = $comment_row['p_com'];



$response_arr[] = array("id" => $postid, "title" => $title, "content" => $content, "type" => $type, "count_comment" => $total_comment,"usern"=>$usern,"pcom"=>$pcom);
    }

    echo json_encode($response_arr);
    exit;
}
```

**below is the frontend in angularjs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body ng-app='myapp'>
        <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl' >

<h2>show posts</h2>
            <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>
                <h1 >{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <div class="post-text">
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>
<div>
<h2>show comments</h2>

<b>Name:</b>{{ post.usern}}  <b>comments</b>: {{ post.pcom}}<br>

({{ post.count_comment}} comments)

</div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);
        fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

                // Fetch post data
                $scope.getPosts = function(){

                    $http({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: 'likeunlike.php',
                        data: {request: 1}
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                        $scope.posts = response.data;
                    });

                }

                $scope.getPosts(); // Fetch post data

            }
        ]);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only fetched the first result after executing the query in `$comment_query`. Perhaps you forgot to put the fetch into a loop (similar to the first loop).

Additionally, since we're going to be using an inner loop, we should use a nested array so that the post and its contents are not repeated with each comment.

The piece of code should look like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $postid = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    $type = -1;

    $post_arr = array(
        "id" => $postid,
        "title" => $title,
        "content" => $content,
        "comments" => array()
    );

    $comment_query = "SELECT username as usern,comment as p_com FROM post_comment WHERE  type=1  and postid=".$postid;
    $comment_result = mysqli_query($con,$comment_query);

    while ($comment_row = mysqli_fetch_array($comment_result)) {
        $total_comment = $comment_row['cntComment'];

        $usern = $comment_row['usern'];
        $pcom = $comment_row['p_com'];

        $post_arr["comments"][] = array(
            "type" => $type,
            "usern" => $usern,
            "pcom" => $pcom
        );
    }
}
```

Additionally, you'll need to modify your frontend code to use `ng-repeat`. Examples can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). Note that since we can simply count the number of comments on the frontend, we removed the `SELECT COUNT(*)` from the backend PHP code.

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
    <b>Name:</b>{{ comment.usern }}
    <b>comments</b>: {{ comment.pcom }}<br>
</div>

({{ post.comments.length }} comments)
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution but It is still displaying one comment per post. it seems that query that loops the post records does not work properly with the query that loops the comment. Is there anyway we can loop post and comment differently and then join them before echoing out.

Comment: You'll need to modify the Angular frontend to loop through the results also. It's been a while since I've used Angular. Let me see if I can get the code out for you.

Comment: I've edited my answer above to reflect what I think needs to be changed